# Sass: How to merge nested import selectors with parent selector?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-sass

#### Background

I have an existing website where I want to import Bootstrap CSS styles. The styles are clashing, so I want to scope the rules.

#### Example

```
// node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_modals.scss

.modal {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

// ---

// my-styles.scss

.my-selector {
   @import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/modals";
}
```

This results in `.my-selector .modal`, but I want to have `.my-selector.modal`.

I want to avoid having to copy-paste the style rules. If I can somehow do it with @extend it would be already great.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Why are you importing `@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/modals";` instead of the Bootstrap SASS source? .. Is this a special project called boostrap-sass?

Comment: Bootstrap v3 was written in Less. There's a Sass version called `bootstrap-sass`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I completely understand the question because `// node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_modals.scss` is not parent of the current/standard Bootstrap SASS files.

If you're using the latest Bootstrap, `_modal.scss` contains all the SASS modal source. So, if you wanted to @import all the modal rules/classes (.modal, .modal-header, .modal-body, etc...) to another parent `my-selector` class it would be...

```
@import "bootstrap";

.modal.my-selector {
    & {
        @import "bootstrap/modal";
    }
}
```

SASS Demo: https://codeply.com/p/XjYSfp0s8H

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this won't work for me. In my case I do not control the element that has the `modal` class. I'm working on a very legacy project that needs to use Bootstrap v3 for now.

For the most part I'm able to scope the styles where I can modify the parent element, but in some cases I would like to do some Sass magic, but that does not seem to be possible without special considerations from the creator of an imported file.